# mysql syntax assistance (for postgres query)

Tags: mysql

can you please advice the correct syntax for mysql 8 which equivalent to postgres following query:

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 FROM aggregator.argument where argumentname = 'DEFAULT_FE_PAGE' AND value = 'NEW')
THEN
update aggregator.argument set value='AA' where name = 'DEFAULT_FE_PAGE';
END IF;
```

thanks

Comment: There is no IF. You could move your EXISTS condition to the WHERE clause at the end of the update statement.

Comment: you dont need if block, add the filter in the update `update aggregator.argument set value='AA' where name = 'DEFAULT_FE_PAGE' and argumentname = 'DEFAULT_FE_PAGE' AND value = 'NEW'`

Comment: @MoulitharanM, that's not equivalent to the original.  Notice that a row found by the EXISTS query doesn't need to be one of the rows to be updated. In the original, there is no such requirement,  just that there is some row. The original is strange, because it tests for a different condition, if that test passes, there still could be zero rows to updated.

Answer (score 0):

Given the nuance that spencer7593 points out, we want to update all rows where `name=DEFAULT_FE_PAGE` only if there exists at least one row with `name=DEFAULT_FE_PAGE` and `value=NEW`.

We can do this with a multi-table UPDATE:

```
UPDATE aggregator.argument AS a1
JOIN aggregator.argument AS a2 USING (name)
SET a1.value='AA' 
WHERE a2.name = 'DEFAULT_FE_PAGE' AND a2.value='NEW';
```

This matches a row `a2` with both conditions, then joins that row to all rows `a1` that have the same `name`, even if they have a different `value`.